# CUDA tiled matrix multiplication explanation

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, nvidia, gpu-shared-memory

I'm trying to understand how [this sample](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/matrixMul/matrixMul.cu) code from CUDA SDK 8.0 works:

```
template <int BLOCK_SIZE> __global__ void
matrixMulCUDA(float *C, float *A, float *B, int wA, int wB)
{
// Block index
int bx = blockIdx.x;
int by = blockIdx.y;

// Thread index
int tx = threadIdx.x;
int ty = threadIdx.y;

// Index of the first sub-matrix of A processed by the block
int aBegin = wA * BLOCK_SIZE * by;

// Index of the last sub-matrix of A processed by the block
int aEnd   = aBegin + wA - 1;

// Step size used to iterate through the sub-matrices of A
int aStep  = BLOCK_SIZE;

// Index of the first sub-matrix of B processed by the block
int bBegin = BLOCK_SIZE * bx;

// Step size used to iterate through the sub-matrices of B
int bStep  = BLOCK_SIZE * wB;

....
....
```

This part of the kernel is quite tricky for me. I know that the matrices A and B are represented as array (*float), and I know also the concept of using shared memory in order to compute the dot product thanks to shared memory chuncks.

My problem is that I don't understand the beginning of the code, in particular 3 specific variables (`aBegin`, `aEnd` and `bBegin`). Could someone make me an example drawing of a possible execution, in order to help me understand how the indexes work in this specific case? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a drawing to understand the values set to the first variables of the CUDA kernel and the overall computation performed:
[image: CUDA matrix computation]

Matrices are stored using a row-major ordering. The CUDA code assume the matrix sizes can be divided by `BLOCK_SIZE`.

The matrices `A`, `B` and `C` are virtually split in blocks according to the kernel CUDA grid. All blocks of `C` can be computed in parallel. For a given dark-grey block of `C`, the main loop walk through the several light-grey blocks of `A` and `B` (in lockstep). Each block is computed in parallel using `BLOCK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE` threads.

`bx` and `by` are the block-based position of the current block within the CUDA grid.
`tx` and `ty` are the cell-based position of the cell computed by the current thread within the current computed block of the CUDA grid.

Here is a detailed analysis for the `aBegin` variable:
`aBegin` refers to the memory location of the first cell of the *first computed block* of the matrix `A`. It is set to `wA * BLOCK_SIZE * by` because each block contains `BLOCK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE` cells and there is `wA / BLOCK_SIZE` blocks horizontally and `by` blocks above the current computed block of `A`. Thus, `(BLOCK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE) * (wA / BLOCK_SIZE) * by = BLOCK_SIZE * wA * by`.

The same logic apply for `bBegin`:
it is set to `BLOCK_SIZE * bx` because there is `bx` block of size `BLOCK_SIZE` in memory before the first cell of the first computed block of the matrix `B`.

`a` is incremented by `aStep = BLOCK_SIZE` in the loop so that the next computed block is the following on the right (on the drawing) of the current computed block of `A`. `b` is incremented by `bStep = BLOCK_SIZE * wB` in the same loop so that the next computed block is the following of the bottom (on the drawing) of the current computed block of `B`.